# Export an Excel file using Laravel-Excel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this piece of code that is used to export an Excel file using Laravel-Excel. But I have doubts about it for the long run. Can the server handle it if there are a hundred requests?

```php
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

class DailyGeneralSheetExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{
    use Exportable;

    public function __construct(array $request, int $diid, int $igid, str $date)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->diid = $diid;
        $this->igid = $igid;
        $this->date = $date;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        $dt = Carbon::parse($this->date);
        $endDt = Carbon::parse($this->date)->lastOfMonth();
        $period = CarbonPeriod::create($this->date, $endDt);
        $ipid = array_pluck($this->request, 'ip_id');
        $inidArr = array_pluck($this->request, 'in_id');
        $inid = array_unique($inidArr);
        $collection = [];
        foreach ($period as $key => $eachDate) {
            $reading = DB::table('instrument')
                    ->where('iv_inid', $inid)
                    ->whereIn('iv_ipid', $ipid)
                    ->whereDate('iv_date', $eachDate)
                    ->whereIn('iv_status', ['N', 'Y', 'A'])
                    ->orderBy('iv_date')->get()->toArray();
            $row = array($eachDate->format('d/m/Y'));
            foreach ($reading as $columnKey => $columnValue) {
                array_push($row, $columnValue->iv_reading);
            }
            array_push($collection, $row);
        }

        return collect($collection);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function headings(): array
    {
        $sheet_header = Arr::pluck($this->request, 'ip_label');

        return Arr::prepend($sheet_header, 'Date');
    }
}
```

As you can see I have to create an array for one month and this makes me worry if this will impact the performance. And for some reason, I feel I wrote code that is not elegant as Laravel does. How do I optimize it?

Comment: Have you tried load testing to see what happens with N hits at once?

Answer (score 1):

The code looks OK. You may want to move the query outside of the `foreach` loop and group the results afterwards. But the `foreach` loop is limited to the number of days in a month, so I don't think that will do very much. That may cause the application to use more memory.

Therefore, I advise testing if the performance is indeed an issue. If so you might want to delegate creating the export to a queue. Queues in Laravel are not hard to implement (surprise!)

[Laravel Queues Documentation 7.x](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues)

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. This looks an assessment of a man-machine interface issue. I am not sure this provides me with an insight about the code presented.

Comment: True, but I did not see any chance for optimising the code - it looks great.